# Swiper navigation doesn't work until animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slider, swiper.js

Swiper 3.4.1 on Windows

I did a slider with arrow navigation, infinite loop and fade effect:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    simulateTouch: false,
    speed: 1600,
    autoplay: 2500,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
    loop: true,
    effect: 'fade',
    fade: {
      crossFade: true
    }
  });
```

#### Expected Behavior

I need to stop animation when click on arrows(next and prev buttons)

#### Actual Behavior

I can't click next or prev buttons while animation is not finished

How can I skip the animation on click?(I haven't found this in the documentation)

ps: it works when I remove loop, but I need it